# How to make LLMs enhance RS effectively? LLMRec: Large Language Models with Graph Augmentation for Recommendation

Tags: recommendation-engine, large-language-model

WSDM 2024: LLMRec: Large Language Models with Graph Augmentation for Recommendation.
Paper & Code & Multimodal(text, images) datasets: https://github.com/HKUDS/LLMRec

How to make LLMs enhance RS effectively?

WSDM 2024: LLMRec: Large Language Models with Graph Augmentation for Recommendation.
Paper & Code & Multimodal(text, images) datasets: https://github.com/HKUDS/LLMRec